# Why would indexing an array to set values of another array affect the indexed arrays values?

Tags: arrays, indexing

I am working on a program in C that parses a text file for values to put into a large matrix (1000x1000 and larger).

The program takes a line from the file, parses it for integers and doubles and stores them into an array of type double. The array looks like:

cleanedCharArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 588.235300, -629.461300, 33.333300, 7.892700};

I am now trying to use this array of doubles to create an integer array of the index values (1 through 4) and a double array of the actual values (the decimal values.)

```
int * getIndexVector(const double * cleanedCharArray)
{
  #define vectorSize (sizeof(cleanedCharArray) / 2)
  static int idxVector[vectorSize];

  idxVector[0] = cleanedCharArray[0];
  idxVector[1] = cleanedCharArray[1];
  idxVector[2] = cleanedCharArray[2];
  idxVector[3] = cleanedCharArray[3];

  return idxVector;
}
```

I created a loop that prints each value at each index to the terminal. After running the function above on the cleanedCharArray, the values of idxVector and cleanedCharArray were as follows:

idxVector = 1, 2, 3, 4
cleanedCharArray = 1, 2, 3, 4, 0.0000, 0.0000, 33.3333, 7.8927

I tried printing the values of cleanedCharArray inbetween each assignment line above (between each idxVector[i] = cleanedCharArray[i]) and it turns out the line:

```
idxVector[1] = cleanedCharArray[1];
```

is responsible for setting idxVector[1] = 2 and cleanedCharArray[4] = 0.00. The line:

```
idxVector[3] = cleanedCharArray[3];
```

is responsible for setting idxVector[3] = 4 and cleanedCharArray[5] = 0.00.

This "bug" renders my cleanedCharArray completely useless because the values are now off.

I understand there needs to be a specific explanation for why the code does this, however I cannot find the reason.

Why would the values of the indexed array change at indexes that are not even used?

Is there a way to make the values not change?

Thank you,

Ryan

Comment: What language are you using? C? If so, do you know that `#define` is a compiler statement? I don't think `double *` has a standard size other than 0. (If you don't know that, then that is the problem)

Comment: I am programming in C, I had to use #define because when I tried to use a variable to set the size of the double it gave me an error since the value wasn't a constant, it was a variable.

Comment: Please read up on what pre-processor statements do. That is your problem. Short version: It calculates that "constant" when preprocessing and replaces it everywhere with the number it finds. That number will be 0 for you

Comment: You use define for things like `#define TRUE 1` to make a "fake boolean", but you can't use it as a constant